# Unhandled rejection: Data is not getting inserted into Mongodb

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, typescript, next.js

> Server is starting at 8080
>   GET / 304 - - 1.952 ms
>   (node:6139) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongooseServerSelectionError: bad auth Authentication failed.
>       at new MongooseServerSelectionError (/Users/abc/Desktop/success/node_modules/mongoose/lib/error/serverSelection.js:22:11)
>       at NativeConnection.Connection.openUri (/Users/abc/Desktop/success/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:808:32)
>       at Mongoose.connect (/Users/abc/Desktop/success/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:333:15)
>       at Object. (/Users/abc/Desktop/success/pages/server.js:18:10)
>       at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1158:30)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1178:10)
>       at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1002:32)
>       at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:901:14)
>       at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:74:12)
>       at internal/main/run_main_module.js:18:47
>   (node:6139) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
>   (node:6139) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
>   GET / 304 - - 0.320 ms
>   GET / 304 - - 0.236 ms
>   GET / 304 - - 0.210 ms

When I run Port 8080 for my serverjs, the file works but no data gets into my mongoDB and I get the above error on my terminal. I only have a server.js page and an index.tsx page. My index.tsx page has a simple Hello world and I am trying to connect Mongodb using the server.js file.

Here is my code:

```
import express from 'express';
import { connect, connection, Schema as _Schema, model } from 'mongoose';
import morgan from 'morgan';
import path from 'path';

const app = express();
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080;
//Success

const MONGODB_URI = 'mongodb+srv://xxxxxxxxxx';

mongoose.connect(MONGODB_URI || 'mongodb://localhost/success', {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true
});

mongoose.connection.on('connected', () => {
        console.log('Mongoose is connected');

    })

//Schema
const Schema = _Schema;
const BlogPostSchema = new Schema({
    title: String,
    body: String,
    date: {
        type: String,
        default: Date.now()
    }
});

//Model
const BlogPost = model('BlogPost', BlogPostSchema);

//Saving data to our mongoDB
const data = {
    title: 'welcome',
    body: 'first post'
};

const newBlogPost = new BlogPost(data);
newBlogPost.save((error) => {
    if (error) {
        console.log("Somethign happened");
    } else {
        console.log("data saved");
    }

});

//HTTP request logger
app.use(morgan('tiny'));

//Routes
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    const data = {
        username: 'caa',
        age: 5
    };
    res.json(data);

});

app.get('/api/name', (req, res) => {
    const data = {
        username: 'caa',
        age: 5
    };
    res.json(data);

});

app.listen(PORT, console.log(`Server is starting at ${PORT}`));
```

Comment: This seems like an authentication issue. Is your DB secured with some sort of authentication? If yes, are you adding the authentication details to the  `MONGODB_URI`?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because mongoose.connect is asynchronous(not very clear from the documentation). Try putting your code within the "connected" event and see if it works:

```
mongoose.connection.on('connected', () => {
    console.log('Mongoose is connected');
    //Schema
    const Schema = _Schema;
    const BlogPostSchema = new Schema({
        title: String,
        body: String,
        date: {
            type: String,
            default: Date.now()
        }
    });

    //Model
    const BlogPost = model('BlogPost', BlogPostSchema);

    //Saving data to our mongoDB
    const data = {
        title: 'welcome',
        body: 'first post'
    };

    const newBlogPost = new BlogPost(data);
    newBlogPost.save((error) => {
        if (error) {
            console.log("Somethign happened");
        } else {
            console.log("data saved");
        }

    });

    //HTTP request logger
    app.use(morgan('tiny'));

    //Routes
    app.get('/', (req, res) => {
        const data = {
            username: 'caa',
            age: 5
        };
        res.json(data);

    });

    app.get('/api/name', (req, res) => {
        const data = {
            username: 'caa',
            age: 5
        };
        res.json(data);

    });

    app.listen(PORT, console.log(`Server is starting at ${PORT}`));

})
```

Comment: After adding your code, the same error arrises.

Error: (node:6170) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongooseServerSelectionError: bad auth Authentication failed.

Comment: Well then make sure mongoDb is running, and that you pass the correct configuration

Comment: Now I am getting this error and what I was lacking was the password. How do I get this error solved as I have entered my password as well. 

(node:6210) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoParseError: URI does not have hostname, domain name and tld